# How do i Square Root a Function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sqrt

I am working on a MonteCarlo simulation model and part of it is to calculate the following formula:

> X = Sqr(1-p)Y + Sqr(p)Z,

Where:

1. Y and Z are randomly obtained values based (idiosyncratic and systematic factors, respectviely) on a standard normal (inv.) distribution, calculated as:

   ```
    Application.WorksheetFunction.NormInv (Rnd(), mean, sd)
   ```
2. p represents a correlation factor.

My aim is to square root a recalled formula, however when I try the following (inserting the first Sqr), it does not work and gives an error:

```
Matrix (n, sims) = (R * Sqr(Application.WorksheetFunction.NormInv(Rnd(), mean, sd))) + (Sqr(1 - R) * RandomS(s, x))
```

where:

**R**: Correlation factor

**RandomS(s,x)**: generated matrix with Z values.

I don't want to go into too much details about the background and other variables, as the only problem I am getting is with Square Rooting the equation.

Error message I recieve reads:

> Run-time error '5':
>
> Invalid procedure call or argument

When I click debug it takes me to the formula, therefore there must be something wrong with the syntax.

Can you help with directly squaring the formula?

Thank you!

Andrew

Comment: Are you getting an error? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I added the error message above. I am usually having problems with writing longer formulas - getting various errors, therefore answering this might help that as well.

Answer (score 3):

Square root is simply `Sqr`.

It works fine in Excel VBA, so for example:

```
MsgBox Sqr(144)
```

...returns `12`.

Just don't confuse it with the syntax for a worksheet function with is `SQRT`.

---

If you're still having an issue with your formula, tit must be with something other than the Square Root function, and I'd suggest you check the values of your variable, and make sure they are properly declared (preferably with `Option Explicit` at the top of the module).

Also make sure that you're passing `Sqr` a *positive* number.

---

Documentation: [**`Sqr` Function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sqr-function)

---

I'm not a math major, but with your formula:

> `X = Sqr(1-p)Y + Sqr(p)Z,`

...you specified how `Y` and `Z` are calculated, so calculate them separately to keep it simple:

```
Dim X as Double, Y as Double, Z as Double
Y = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormInv (Rnd(), mean, sd)
Z = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormInv (Rnd(), mean, sd)
```

Assuming the comma is not supposed to be in the formula, and having no idea what `p` is, your final code to calculate `X` is:

> `X = Sqr(1-p) * Y + Sqr(p) * Z`

Comment: This is a helpful answer and would use it as an alternative option, thank you! It would be also useful if there is a way to incorporate the 'Sqr' into the formula as specified above.